# "AMP Stories" for mobile visitors but "AMP Websites" for desktop visitors?

Tags: amp-html

Is there some way to do [AMP Stories](https://amp.dev/about/stories/) for mobile visitors but a regular [AMP Websites](https://amp.dev/about/websites/) page for Desktop visitors?

Here's an [example AMP Story](https://edition-cnn-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/edition.cnn.com/ampstories/world/protecting-the-antarctic-a-journey-to-a-continent-in-distress) that doesn't look ideal on Desktop but could work well for a homepage on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unaware of a standard way to substitute a story with a webpage on desktop, but AMP stories do support [landscape orientation and full bleed desktop experience](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-story/?format=stories#landscape-orientation-and-full-bleed-desktop-experience-opt-in) .

Comment: I hadn't seen that previously. That solved my dilemma. Thank you!

Comment: Sure! Glad this was helpful!

Answer (score -1):

No. The way the CNN story looks on mobile is standard, nothing bad about it.

Comment: Well... bad for the layout of the homepage of a website on desktop. Looks fine as a homepage for a mobile visitor.